# Apply palette colors on set of functions

Tags: colors, gnuplot, palette

In gnuplot you can define and plot a set of functions quite simply:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
unset key
f(a,x) = a*x
plot for [a=0:100:2] f(a,x)
```

However I want to color the sets according to the value of `a` with a palette

```
set palette defined ( 0 'red' , 100 'green' )
```

The following does not work:

```
#random range from palette picked ( -> 0)
plot for [a=0:100:2] f(a,x) lc palette

#error no output
plot for [a=0:100:2] x:(f(a,x)):a lc palette

#colors not from palette
plot for [a=0:100:2] f(a,x) lc a
```

How to apply palette colors to a set of functions in gnuplot?

gnuplot Version 5.2 on linux

Answer (score 1):

Picking colors from the palette by value is possible with `lc palette cb <value>`. Notably the range of the colorbox (`cb`) needs to be matched to the palette range:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 350,300
set output 'test.png'

f(a,x)=a*x

set palette defined ( 0 'red',  100 'green' )
set cbrange [0:100]

unset key
set xrange [0:10]

plot for [a=0:100:10] f(a,x) lc palette cb a lw 3
```

[image]